# difference between CI active record update and update_batch

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Im using CI for my application. I am currently wondering if what is the difference between update() and update batch? maybe in terms of performance or flow?

I have this sample snippet for update():

```
$data = array(
  array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
 );
 $this->db->where('id', 1)->update('user', $data);
```

for update_batch();

```
 $data = array(
  array(
      'id'   => 1,
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'id'   => 1,
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
 );
 $this->db->update_batch('user', $data, 'id');
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update). Is there anything there that you do not understand?

Comment: you see my snippet is a bit different from the documentation, that's why I'm asking if there are differences or advantage over the other.

Comment: I am asking here, because the documentation is not enough to supply my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a difference: the number of times you connect to the database, which **may hit greatly your performance** when updating a large number of rows. When performing several updates on bulk, you connect one time to the database and update all the rows, otherwise, you connect one time per update and that time is added to your execution time, damaging your performance. To give you an idea of improvement, no bulk vs bulk was 3 minutes against 7 seconds one time I had to update 15.000 rows in a small server.

About the data batch you show us, you're doing it wrong: the idea is updating TWO DIFFERENT ROWS, so the id (the field you are using to check to select your rows) MUST BE different if you're updating them, otherwise you update one row, and then the same row again. Check the difference below:

```
 $data = array(
  array(
      'id'   => 1,
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      // This id MUST BE of a different row if you want to achieve something, XD
      'id'   => 2,
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
 );
 $this->db->update_batch('user', $data, 'id');
```

Comment: oh, I see thank you. Assuming that id is just a foreign key and the primary key is rowID. will that do?

Comment: no, update_batch will use the field you specify to update, so if you want to update fields with rowID, you should use rowID